# Is it possible to save images to facebook via qr code?

Tags: javascript, c#, php, facebook, unity-game-engine

I'm new into facebook development.

I was thinking if it's possible to share images in facebook via scanning a QR Code. I know it's possible, but the tricky part here is that, the source image is NOT saved in a database.

Here's the workflow to give you guys a clearer understanding.

1. System saves photo locally (cache)
2. System shows QR code to user
3. User downloads image through the FB QR code
4. User can share, or directly share the image after scanning the QR Code.

My first idea here would be that the system saves all photos in a database, thus a link can be parsed and FB can easily access that image anytime, anywhere.

However, I was wondering if it's possible to have the same feature, but instead of having a DB, all the images saved by the system is stored locally - thus having only a brief amount of time/current session before it gets lost again.

I'll be using Unity/C# primarily, and use other languages as well, but I'm still exploring what's the best implementation for it.

Any input would be appreciated. Thanks!

--EDIT--

I've done more research and yes, my idea is perfectly valid IF it is saved onto an online DB. But I'd love to have some insight if it's possible for the image to NOT BE saved in a DB, and is still able to be shared via facebook.

FB SDK shares images through links, that's why links are okay. But locally saved images doesn't have long storage links (It can be parsed, but after the session is destroyed, the link is no longer valid since the image wasn't saved in the first place)

Comment: It is a little bit unclear what the use of this would be (or maybe I didnt understand it correctly): Are points 3 and 4 on another device? How does this device gets the image when you say its stored locally on the device which is used in points 1 and 2  so it needs some way to make it accessible to the other device(3+4); IF you use only 1 device for all 4 points, there is no need to scan your just now generated QR code unless you print it. In this case just generate a link as QR Code.

Comment: Yes. 3 and 4 are on another device.

Comment: Here are more information:
1. Device 1 is a Kinect-powered PC that is used for an AR (augmented reality) activation
2. Device 1 must send the saved photos that other users capture to the user's device
3. I need to find a way how to get those photos to the other device without going through a database

Comment: To share data there must be a direct or indirect(server, "database", Big QRCode with ImageData, ...) connection between those two devices. So you could upload a QR Code Image with the information on (where to get the data and) which data to get to Facebook. The client can connect with this information to the server and request the Image. FB would only see the QRCode, not the original Image.

Comment: Like @FrankM said, you would need a server connection. If you would like send data (including images) without writing to a DB, it is possible, for example with MQTT.

Comment: Do you want to share a link with a specific thumbnail - or upload an actual photo? The latter of course works with local image data as well.

Comment: @CBroe Actual photo needed. I'm looking for an option where I can send in data to a different device using QR codes, but preferably without a DB (and hopefully) without an internet connection.

Comment: @EdwinChua Once again like what you commented here before, I'm sorry but you're giving very generic answers.

Comment: Considering https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Storage, I doubt it would make sense to try and “send” a complete image via QR code. // Who/what is “system” in this scenario to begin with? Some sort of server-side component? Then you can send the image data to the Facebook API from there, no need to get it directly onto the client device to begin with. _“(and hopefully) without an internet connection”_ - why that particular requirement? “Offline” interactions with a social media platform would be a weird thing to begin with, and I can’t see any actual need for that.